# Error datos Float en C

Tags: c

Estoy empezando con C y un programa muy sencillo me da un error que me está volviendo loco.

El caso es que me pide el nombre, lo escribo y luego cuando debe pedirme el sueldo, gastos, etc salta y me termina el programa sin pedirme datos.

Adjunto código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char name[20];
    float sueldo,ocio,comida,transporte;

    printf("Digame su nombre y apellidos: \n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Digame su sueldo mensual (en euros): \n");
    scanf("%f", &sueldo);
    printf("Cuanto gasta diariamente en ocio (en euros)?: \n");
    scanf("%f", &ocio);
    printf("Cuanto gasta diariamente en comida (en euros)?: \n");
    scanf("%f", &comida);
    printf("Cuanto gasta diariamente en transporte (en euros)?: \n");
    scanf("%f", &transporte);

    printf("***********************************************************************************\n");
    printf("*****\t\t\t%s\t\t\t*****\n",name);
    printf("\t%%Ocio\t%%Comida\t%%Transporte\n");
    printf("\t%.2f%%\t%.2f%%\t%.2f%%\t\n",ocio/sueldo, comida/sueldo, transporte/sueldo);
    printf("*****\t\t\t\t\t\t*****");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tGasto semanal");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t%.2f",(ocio+comida+transporte)*12);


    return 0;
}
```

¿Por qué?

Comment: Funciona bien, debe ser que estas ingresando la `,` como decimal.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. El problema es que al poner nombre y apellido lo separaba con un espacio y es scanf solo atrapa datos hasta el espacio y deja el apellido para la siguiente variable. Si se pone todo junto o solo el nombre funciona

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta usar & en los scanf que piden un Sting porque son punteros

Solo tiene que ser:

```
Scanf("%s",string);
```